# Setting Time-To-Live and Expiration for RabbitMQ Queue in Ballerina Using RabbitMQ Client

Tags: rabbitmq, ballerina

I need to set Time-To-Live (TTL) and expiration for a RabbitMQ queue. I am using the RabbitMQ client in Ballerina to interact with RabbitMQ. However, I couldn't find clear documentation or examples of how to achieve this. Are there any specific ways in the Ballerina RabbitMQ client that I should be using for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` field of the RabbitMQ [QueueConfig](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerinax/rabbitmq/latest#QueueConfig) to provide any additional configurations (apart from the standard configs defined in the same record) when declaring a queue.

Here's a complete code sample which demonstrates the aforementioned approach.

```php
import ballerinax/rabbitmq;

public function main() returns error? {

    // Create a RabbitMQ client
    rabbitmq:Client newClient = check new ("localhost", 8080);

    // Define the additional arguments as a map of JSON
    map<json> arguments = {
        "x-message-ttl": 60000,
        "x-expires": 800000
    };

    // Declare a RabbitMQ queue with the specified arguments
    check newClient->queueDeclare("demo", {arguments});

    // Close the RabbitMQ client
    check newClient->close();
}
```